# Using laravel’s policies to delete all users’ posts as an Adnin

Tags: laravel, policy

Please I need help with Laravel’s policy. I have two guards (Admin and Users with two models of same guards). I’m able to fetch all users posts inside admin’s dashboard. However, I can’t view them since I’m not logged in as a user (show post view is still locked into auth user’s profile for now). Can I possibly use Laravel’s policy from admin’s dashboard to delete a user’s post without logging in as a user? Here is my code so far....

```
use App\AdminPost;
use App\UserPost;
```

```
{
protected $policies = [
AdminPost::class => AdminPostPolicy::class,
UserPost::class => UserPostPolicy::class,
]:
public function boot()
{
$this->registerPolicies();
}



class AdminPolicy
{
public function delete(what goes in here ????)
return $......
}
```

This is all I can think of so far. I really need help please. Thanks

Comment: There is a `before` method you can use with Policies that will allow you to do a check for something like an admin and just authorize them for all the actions

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take a look in the documentation carefully to implement this method.